# WPF ComboBox: how to know when the item container (when was opened) lost focus

Tags: wpf, combobox, behavior

i want to create a behavior in which a `ComboBox` drop down is closing when lost focus.
My first try was:

```
public class ComboBoxLostFocusBehavior : Behavior<ComboBox> {

    protected override void OnAttached() {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen = false;
    }
}
```

but LostFocus event is referring only to the toggle part, not the items container.

How can I refer to the drop down list?

I want: **when drop down list lost focus -> drop down is closing**

**EDIT:**

I think the question is misunderstood. ComboBox has 2 main parts, the part you see when it is closed (lets call it A), and the drop down list (lets call it B). LostFocus is referring only to part A. So in the scenario I presented in question, which is wrong, you open the drop down list, move the mouse from A to B, and when just leaving A and arriving B, B is closed (by the behavior). So to conclude, LostFocus is the wrong way to go and I am looking for something else to imply that the drop down (B) lost focus.

[image]

Comment: do you mean when the dropdown is closed? or when dropdown is closing? or when the dropdown is opened and looses focus which makes it close?

Comment: when drop down is closed, i think, it cannot be in focus. So when drop down is opened and than lost focus. How to capture this?

Comment: you should user SelectionChanged .
What is it you need to do on LostFocus ?

Comment: Selection changed is not good since the selection is (kind of) multi selection. My template for items is value with check box, and on selection you can check a few before closing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly from question/comments you want to know if the combobox looses focus after the dropdown is opened.

you may use the `IsDropDownOpen` property in LostFocus event, eg

```
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen)
                {
                    //dropdown is open and control is loosing focus, you may perhaps want to close it
                    AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen = false;
                }
            };
    }
```

or you can attach the `DropDownOpened` & `DropDownClosed` events and maintain your own state, eg

```
    bool isDropDownOpen;
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.DropDownOpened += (s, e) => isDropDownOpen = true;
        AssociatedObject.DropDownClosed += (s, e) => isDropDownOpen = false;

        AssociatedObject.LostFocus += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (isDropDownOpen)
                {
                    //dropdown is open and control is loosing focus, you may perhaps want to close it
                    AssociatedObject.IsDropDownOpen = false;
                }
            };
    }
```

or perhaps use these events in some other way as desired, eg

```
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.DropDownClosed += (s, e) =>
            {
                //your action on dropdown close
            };
    }
```

Comment: I think the question was misunderstood here, please see the edit.

Comment: I did saw the edit you've made. Appreciated if you could also provide the steps to simulate the same?

Comment: by steps I mean by how to simulate lost focus on dropdown list? does it mean that after opening the dropdown `B` click the combo control `A`? or something else?

Comment: Open A > move mouse from A to B (B got focus) > leave B (B lost focus) - here i want B to close